# Python Subtracting Elements in a Lists from Previous Element

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a loop that produces multiple lists such as these:

```
  [1,6,2,8,3,4]

  [8,1,2,3,7,2]

  [9,2,5,6,1,4]
```

*For each list, I want to subtract the first two elements, and then use that value to then subtract the third element from.*

For example, the first list should end up looking like:

```
  [-5, 4,-6, 5,-1]
```

I have tried to manually do this, but there are too many lists to do this and it would take too much time.

How would I do that in the least amount of lines of code?

Comment: Can you show us your attempt? StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. It's suppose to be collaborative.

Comment: Why should the first array result in [-5, -7, -13, ...] instead of [-5, -7, -9, ...]?

Comment: Not really clear: do you want to substract the first two elements from all the others, or do you want to substract the first through nth element from the (n+1)th?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean something like (python2) `[a[0] - a[1]] + [e1 - e0 for (e0, e1) in zip(a[1: ], a[: -1])][1: ]`, but am not answering, as I downvoted this question (sorry, you should show the code you tried).

Answer (score 7):

From your updated example, it seems like, given a list `[a, b, c, d, ...]` you want `[a-b, b-c, c-d, d-e, ...]` as a result. For this, you should `zip` the list with itself, offset by one position, and subtract the elements in the pairs.

```
lst = [1,6,2,8,3,4]
res = [x-y for x, y in zip(lst, lst[1:])]    
print(res)  # [-5, 4, -6, 5, -1]
```

If the lists are much longer, you might instead create an iterator, use `tee` to duplicate that iterator, and advance one of the iterators one position with `next`:

```
import itertools    
i1, i2 = itertools.tee(iter(lst))
next(i2)
res = [x-y for x, y in itertools.izip(i1, i2)]  # or just zip in Python 3
```

Comment: Question, how does the performance of `tee` compare to simply using an `islice`? e.g.: `[x-y for x,y in zip(a,itertools.islice(a,1,None))]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Good suggestion; making one iterator should indeed be enough. Tested with a list of 1000 random elements, and performance is still very similar in all three variants.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> my_list = [1,6,2,8,3,4]
>>> [my_list[i] - my_list[i+1] for i in range(len(my_list) -1)]
[-5, 4, -6, 5, -1]
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to optimize your code, so it runs faster. Reducing the lines of code wont improve this since you are looping through lists.

From what I can tell, your problem can't be solved in under n-1 subtractions (where n is the number of input values). However there might be a more effective solution if you know how the lists are created.

Comment: But he asked for the lowest amount of code, not if he could do it in _n_ subtractions.

Comment: He also said that his code takes too much time which isn't strictly related to the number code lines...

Comment: _How would I do that in the least amount of lines of code?_ , was his exact question. Shouldn't that be the main question that is answered, and something like your answer above would be a side note?

Comment: My apology for the downvote. To begin with, I think you misuderstood the question. The OP said that *doing it manually* would take too long because there are too many lists. Irrespectively, what you wrote is a comment, not an answer, which is why I've downvoted it.

Comment: You both have a point there. I hope the edited version is easier to understand